# sequelize include works only if we do db:sync force

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My Model Definitions are

// models/chat_message.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var ChatMessage = sequelize.define('chat_message', {
         message: DataTypes.TEXT,
         message_type: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        underscored: true,
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at',
        deletedAt : 'deleted_at',
        paranoid: true
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
            }
        }
    });
    return ChatMessage;
};
```

// models/chat_message_stat.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var ChatMessageStat = sequelize.define('chat_message_stat', {
        chat_message_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        delivered: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    }, {
        underscored: true,
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at',
        deletedAt : 'deleted_at',
        paranoid: true
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
            }
        }
    });
    return ChatMessageStat;
};
```

// Import models like this

```
var ChatMessage = sequelize.import("./models/chat_message");
var ChatMessageStat = sequelize.import("./models/chat_message_stat");
```

// And then the line to retrieve all messages with their stat

```
ChatMessage.hasMany(ChatMessageStat);
ChatMessageStat.belongsTo(ChatMessageStat);

ChatMessage.findAndCountAll({
        where: params,
        include : [{model:ChatMessageStat}]
    }).then(function(all_messages) {
         // do something with messages
    });
```

The above **include works only** when I do

```
sequelize.sync({force:true}).then(function () {
    //
});
```

But sync with {force:true} drops and creates all tables which I don't want, if i have to restart the application.

Sequelize documentation is not showing me the right direction - any inputs here?

I use sequelize-cli to create migrations - defined foreign key constraints in the migrations only. So I dont actually need sync() to create foreigns keys.

Comment: What happens without `sync({force:true})`? Do you get the data only from `ChatMessage`?

Comment: Yes and the include ChatMessageStat array empty

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Maybe it's missing the [primary key](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/legacy/#primary-keys) definition? Also, I would compare the generated databases from CLI and `sync({force:true})` to see if the CLI version has everything it needs.

Comment: everything is same except " ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE" - i didn't specify this in my migration whereas sync is adding this. Guess this has nothing to do with "include"

Comment: I created a new DB manually ( not with migrations , not with sync ) by copy pasting table structure from sync'ed DB and now its working fine.  Looks like I am missing something in migrations. Will keep you posted - if the missing thing is only "ON DELETE CASCADE....."  or int(11) vs int(10)

Comment: **solved** : i have paranoid true and deleted_at is set to {allowNull : false} - I removed this allowNull and it works now.  
The difference is in the table data. With allowNull:false - deleted_at value is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 else null.

Comment: @denisazevedo  thanks a lot - your idea to compare generated DB solved this.